# Finding solution to a non-linear differential equation

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

I am given the equation below, where b is the average number of births (b=8), and d is the average number of deaths (d=3), and I am given an initial condition: P(0) = 500.

[image]

Given the above values, I have solved for P(t) = 500 * exp(5*t).

I am then asked:

[image]

I have put in the new value of "d" into equation (1) to receive:

dP/dt = 5P - P^2/800.

I am unsure how to solve this as it is not linear (and we have not yet covered how to solve non-linear DE's), and I can't seem to figure out how the fraction given in c) could possibly help...

I appreciate any help,

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\frac {dP}{dt} = 5P - \frac {P^2}{800}\\
\frac {dP}{dt} =   \frac {(4000 - P)P}{800}$

Which looks like the reciprocal of the partial fraction in part c)

$\int \frac  {800}{(4000-P)P}\ dP = \int \ dt$

using c)

$\int \frac  {0.2}{4000-P}+\frac  {0.2}{P}\ dP = \int \ dt$

Which will give you a pair of log functions.  Using what you know about logarithms, you will make them into one function.  Exponentiate both sides, and solve for $P.$

Answer (score 0):

Write your equation in the form
$$\frac{\frac{dp(t)}{dt}}{-\frac{1}{800}p(t)^2+5p(t)}=1$$ it is separable.